# Create a dynamically named record in DeepstreamIO

Tags: javascript, deepstream.io

I'm trying to create a record that is called the same way it's called in our database. I'm trying to create this record from the client with the regular getRecord()-call. The error I get is that I can't do anything on the record, and when I look at the object its isReady is always false.

This is how I'm trying to create the record:

1. Register (inserts an unique ID in the DB)
2. Login (front end knows the unique ID)
3. Login with the Deepstream client (this works)
4. Create/get the record with client.record.getRecord('path')

It seems like the record is created etc. but the isReady is always false and I can't use the record at all.

I've tried to create a record with a static name and this works as it should.

So, any ideas why I can't create a Deepstream record with an ID from the database?
The ID looks like this: 4d06902a-57f7-4ea8-b76b-f487cb369c5b (I'm using RethinkDB if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using whenReady(callback) before attempting to use the record. You might also provide an example of statically and dynamically named records you are using.

Are you saying that calling getRecord with the Uid from client.getUid works OK but an id from RethinkDB will not? Please supply the actual error you're seeing or some sample code: http://codeshare.io/

Comment: The one problem I had was that whenReady() was never called from the record, however, by some magical power, it worked late last night for some reason (love programming when that happens..). Anyway, it works as it should now.

I noticed though that to get access to the record in the database I needed to get the value of ds_id from the database, and not the value that id had.  I haven't found anything in the docs that says this.

Anyway, it works as it should now =)

Gonna accept your answer since I didn't use whenReady() before your post which helped me on the way!